# Prove the following is true by applying universal generalization

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

For all integers m, if 7 is a factor of m then 7 is not a factor of m + 6.

Assuming the left side is true, 7k=m for some k in integers
That would give me 7k+6 on the right side. Now I could just end the proof there and say m+6 cannot be represented as 7*some integer but I'm not sure if that would work. Is there any other way to go about this?

Comment: $7j = 7k+6\,\Rightarrow\,7(j-k)=6\ \ $

Answer (score 1):

Suppose otherwise that $7 \mid (m+6) \to m+6 = 7k \to 6 = 7k - m = 7k - 7n = 7(k-m) \to  7 \mid 6$ contradiction.

Comment: How did you get from 7k-m = 7k-7n? Is that with the assumption that 7 is a factor of m? And then it became 7(k-m) was that m supposed to be a n? Thanks